# Calculate % change month to month

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to calculate net revenue % change from month to month in PowerBI.

Following [Time Patterns](https://www.daxpatterns.com/time-patterns/) "Period Comparison Pattern", which states:

> For example, the month-over-month calculation (MOM) compares the current selection with the same selection one month before.

And [This Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerBI/comments/6wzx8t/calculating_percent_change/), which states:

> Expanding on this: CALCULATE ( SUM ( YourValueCol ), PREVIOUSMONTH ( YourDateCol ) )

I feel like I'm following these. See below:

---

Selected Model Dimensions:

- Date Model: `Month` (which is month numbers in a year)
- NR: (Calculated: `SUM(Orders[Unit Net Revenue USD])`)

Gives:

```
Month | NR
----------------------
1       $5       
2       $6
3       $7
```

Selected Model Dimensions for Previous Month:

- Date Model: `Previous Month` (which is month numbers in a year)
- NR: (Calculated: `SUM(Orders[Unit Net Revenue USD])`)

Gives:

```
Previous Month | NR
----------------------
1                $6       
2                $7
3                $8
---------------------
Total:            $21
```

So I try to compare current month NR to previous month NR to eventually get % change:

```
This Month NR = CALCULATE(SUM(Orders[Unit Net Revenue USD]), 'Date - Period'[Month]) // Month = 2 (February)

Prior Month NR = CALCULATE(SUM(Orders[Unit Net Revenue USD]), 'Date - Period'[PreviousMonth]) // Month = 1 (January)

% Change = DIVIDE([This Month NR], [Prior Month NR], BLANK())-1

// Also tried:

% Change = (([This Month NR] - [Prior Month NR])/ [Prior Month NR])
```

For `This Month NR`, It's giving me the total sum of NR per row, and for `Prior Month NR`, it's giving me the expected values. Why is it giving the total sum per year for each month? E.g.,

```
Year |  Month  | This Month NR               | Prev Month NR
------------------------------------------------------------------
2015     1       $18 ($5 + $6 + $7 for 2015)  $6               
2015     2       $18                          $7
2015     3       $18                          $8 
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected:

```
Year |  Month  | This Month NR               | Prev Month NR
------------------------------------------------------------------
2015     1       $5                          $4               
2015     2       $6                          $5
2015     3       $7                          $6 
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

If I do the following as calculated fields

```
NR Measure = SUM('Retailer Sales'[Net Revenue])
This Month NR = CALCULATE([NR Measure], 'Date'[Month Num])
Prior Month NR = CALCULATE([NR Measure], 'Date'[Previous Month])
```

Then filter by `dimension Year` & `dimension Month Num` & `This Month NR` & `Prior Month NR` I get:

```
Year  | Month   | This Month NR | Prev Month NR
------------------------------------------------------------------
2015     1       $6              $6               
2015     2       $7              $7
2015     3       $8              $8 
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected (again):

```
Year  | Month   | This Month NR | Prev Month NR
------------------------------------------------------------------
2015     1       $6              $5               
2015     2       $7              $6
2015     3       $8              $7 
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For previous month, if I try instead `Prior Month NR = CALCULATE([NR Measure], PREVIOUSMONTH('Retailer Sales'[Date]))` — `Prior Month NR` is simply blank for the same filters.

What am I doing wrong in DAX?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You were so close initially with `PREVIOUSMONTH()`! This is a [time-intelligence function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax) that allows you to manipulate the time period over which an expression is calculated. This is different from creating a shifted month column because DAX doesn't know that values in `'Date'[Previous Month Num]` are equivalent to values in `'Date'[Month Num]`. To the DAX engine, there is no relationship between the two.

**DATEADD() VS PREVIOUSMONTH()**

To calculate change over time, there are a few time intelligence functions that will work. However, an important selection criteria is that the base period and the prior period be the same length so the % difference is a valid comparison.

`DATEADD()` shifts the date values passed to it by a set interval, while `PREVIOUSMONTH()` finds the first date selected, and returns the prior whole month.

```
INPUT_DATE_RANGE     |DATEADD(…,-1,MONTH)  |PREVIOUSMONTH()     
---------------------+---------------------+--------------------
12/1/2023-12/31/2023 |11/1/2023-11/30/2023 |11/1/2023-11/30/2023
10/1/2023-12/31/2023 |9/1/2023-11/30/2023  |9/1/2023-9/30/2023
```

The beauty of `DATEADD()` is that the duration of the ranges is always the same. While `PREVIOUSMONTH()` may be useful sometimes, in a period over period change expression, having both date ranges the same size is very important.

**Month Over Month Syntax**

The textbook option to get % change would be to perform `this_month / previous_month - 1`. However, when the prior month is zero/blank, this returns `-1`, which is not helpful when you have a large number of empty intersections.

The mathematically equivalent `( this_month - previous_month ) / previous_month`, on the other hand will return a blank value when wrapped inside the `DIVIDE()` function when prior month is zero/blank. The `DIVIDE()` function returns `BLANK()` on division by zero.

Finally, by declaring previous_month as a variable, we can eliminate evaluating it twice.

```
VAR previous_month =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Orders[Unit Net Revenue USD]),
        DATEADD( 'Date'[Date], -1, MONTH )
    )
RETURN
DIVIDE(
    SUM(Orders[Unit Net Revenue USD]) - previous_month ,
    previous_month 
)
```